# heavy quark pair spin states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quarks

Apparently, heavy quark pair can have "axial-vector" spin state, "vector" spin state, and two different "tensor" spin states.

Can anyone explain to me what they are and why this is the case?

Thank you!

Comment: *"Apparently"*...from what is this apparent?

Comment: Sorry, nothing is apparent to me. I am just saying this is the case, and I do not know what they are and why it is the case.

Comment: I meant to ask where you read that statement.